# Issues with second lan

Tags: networking, ethernet, cisco-router

I have the following setup

**Superhub3** 192.168.0.1
**eth1** 192.168.0.10

**CISCO ASA 5505** internal 192.168.1.1
**eth2** 169.254.x.x

When directly plugging **ASA** into **eth1**, i **can** access **192.168.1.1**
However, when the **ASA** is connected to **eth2**, it results in **169.254.x.x** address.

Under Network Settings on **Win10 eth2** is connected / **Unidentified network**.

I tried the manual settings shown below, but no change.

[image]

**Q. How can i get the eth2 working simultaneously so i can access 192.168.1.1 from eth2, on the same machine as eth1 on 192.168.0.1?**

**Diagram Added**
[image]

Comment: You don't appear to be running DHCP on your ASA, from what I understand. Can you draw a diagram, or better document exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the access was working to the ASA, windows added a default route for all traffic to go via it, rather than via your original default route to the superhub.

Connect up everything, then print the routing table:

`route print` in a command prompt.

You'll likely see 2 default routes.

Delete the default routes:

`route delete default` x2

Then add the correct default route manually:

`route add default gw 192.168.0.1`

Now everything 'should' just work.

Comment: i shall try this and respond with outcome, regards.